# Kusto Query to merge tables

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am new here for Kusto Query Language. I am exploring few concepts of Azure Data Explorer and I would to like to write a function that performs the merge (as we do in SQL). I tried few queries, but data is only inserting as new records and this is creating the duplicate data in my ADX table.

Below is my requirement.

I have a **employee_temp** table, where I keep the data from different sources. Once data comes into this table, it should merge with my main table **employee**.

** When target table (employee) has a record already with empid, then perform update.

** When target table (employee) do not have a record with empid, then perform insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a [materialized view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-overview#materialized-views-use-cases) with an `arg_max` aggregation.

Comment: After little research, I understand that ADX will allow only appending of data and no updates are supported. So, Is there any possible to have only latest data in my ADX table. When new data for same unique id comes in, can we delete the old record of it.

Comment: The suggested solution answers your need.